# In ember.js/QUnit integration tests, how do you make QUnit wait for a model to finish loading before making an assertion?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit

This is my test code.

```
test("user login", function(){
  visit("/sessions/new").then(function() {
    fillIn('input[name=email]', 'test@email.com');
    fillIn('input[type=password]', '1234');
    click('button[type=submit]').then(function() {
      equal(find('.dropdown-anchor', '#ember-testing').text(), 'test@email.com', "Menu should contain email 'test@email.com'");
    });
  });
});
```

Clicking submit triggers a HTTP request for a session. Once successfully completed, it updates the app menu to have the logged in user email address.

How do you make QUnit wait for the session HTTP request to complete before checking if the page has been updated?

**Update: Solved**

It turns out I have a custom method to create the new session that sits outside of the ember data convention. Once I added `Ember.run.begin();` and `Ember.run.end();` in the ajax request, the test started to work. See here for more details: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html

Answer (score 2):

Each of the ember-testing helpers returns a promise that fulfills when all resulting async behavior is complete. So to wait for the session http request to complete, try the following:

```
test("user login", function(){
  visit("/sessions/new").then(function() {
    return fillIn('input[name=email]', 'test@email.com');
  }).then(function() {
    return fillIn('input[type=password]', '1234');
  }).then(function() {
    return click('button[type=submit]');
  }).then(function() {
    equal(find('.dropdown-anchor', '#ember-testing').text(), 'test@email.com', "Menu should contain email 'test@email.com'");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although it hasn't solved my issue completely, it has helped me clarify the problem. I had followed this tutorial http://pivotallabs.com/playing-with-ember-js-and-devise/ to setup my current session in the `Ember.Application.initializer`. It seems that QUnit is not waiting for asyc events associated with the currentSession controller because it is outside of the current page template. If I redirect it to a page that uses a value from the session record directly in it's template, it does wait and it works.

Comment: Further update. It turns out it is to do with the order I set the `Ember.Application.initializer` and the `App.reset();` in the test `setup` I was reseting the app the then defining the initializer which is the wrong order. Once I set the initilizer first and then reset the app, everything is green.